# How to query team member name and capacity in Rally developer depending upon iteration?

Tags: javascript, rally

I have tried several things to query both the team member name and capacity in Rally developer depending upon iteration.  One of the challenges I run into is that the team member name and capacity are under two different types.  So, matching the team member names with the capacity has been a challenge.

One of my failed attempts in accomplishing this is as follows:

```
 var queryConfig = { 
    key: "teamMember", 
    type: "User", 
    fetch: "UserName,Role", 
    query: '(TeamMemberships != "")'
 };

 var queryByUserName = {
    key: "teamDataByUser", type: "UserIterationCapacity", 
    fetch: "Capacity,ObjectID", 
    query: rally.sdk.util.Query.or(ownerQueries)
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the user's capacity and that users name in one query using dependent field fetching.

```
 var queryByUserName = {
    key: "teamDataByUser", type: "UserIterationCapacity", 
    fetch: "Capacity,ObjectID,User,DisplayName", 
    query: rally.sdk.util.Query.or(ownerQueries)
 };
```

This query will return data that looks like:

```
{
  ObjectID: 64265714,
  Capacity: 6,
  User: {
    _ref: "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/x/user/1234.js",
    ObjectID: 1234,
    DisplayName: "Cindy"
  },
  _type: "UserIterationCapacity"
}
```