# fetching capacity of team

Tags: rally

I am working on report that shows the Velocity - vs. Capacity in % of scrum team using rally app2.0 SDK.

I have looked for a way to get the Capacity of team but fail to find! any one can help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the user's sprint capacity you'll want to query on UserIterationCapacity. While the following example's code pertains to AppSDK 1.0, the query syntax is going to be fairly similar to that outlined in this posting:

[How to query team member name and capacity in Rally developer depending upon iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436392/how-to-query-team-member-name-and-capacity-in-rally-developer-depending-upon-ite)

Following is an example of a query for UserIterationCapacity corresponding to a particular Sprint within a specific Project of interest.

```
        var queryConfig = null;
        var projectOID = "12345678910";
        var selectedIteration = "My Iteration";

        var capacityQueryString = '((Iteration.Name = ' + '"' + 
                selectedIteration + 
                '") AND (Project.ObjectID = "' + 
                projectOID +
                 '"))';
        console.log(capacityQueryString);

        queryConfig = {
            key: "usercapacities", 
            type: "UserIterationCapacity", 
            fetch: "Capacity,User,Role,EmailAddress,DisplayName,UserName",
            query: capacityQueryString
        };

        rallyDataSource.findAll(queryConfig, processResults);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, can you please suggest an efficient query to get the total capacity of an iteration if there is one? I trying to avoid fetching all teamusers and sum the capacity.

Comment: Understood the example is AppSDK 1.0, however, the capacityQueryString is what you're interested in setting your model filter to be in AppSDK 2 :-)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed example, If I understand well I need to extract the sums->capacity from the returned.

QueryResult
Errors 
Warnings 
TotalResultCount 193
StartIndex 1
PageSize
 20
Results 
Object 
Object
Object
Object
Object
Object

Sums 
capacity 1141.95


but I fail to do so!
in
_onDataLoaded: function(store, data) {
                   var records = [];
       
                    Ext.Array.each(data, function(record) {
  
 
                    });

I have access to the results objects! how could I access the sums which is in the same level of Results?
?

Comment: This is a good question, since as you note Sums lives at the same level as results in the REST response. I'd recommend posting this as a followup question - try to figure out how to pull Sums out of AppSDK results.